# how to Count (track) Local notification in background mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification which fire every minutes. I have done that part. But my problem is I want to count the notification and (count=15) then it's stop it. I can do that part in application running state. How can I achieve in background mode?

And also I want to track how many notification are fire? Is it possible in background mode.

```
//below is my notification delegate method
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
   if (notification) { 
   // notification code goes here
   }
}
```

Any demo code then appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you send notification exact 15 times rather to check condition in didReceiveLocalNotification

Comment: @ShehbazKhan my requirement is when u set notification then it repeat every minutes.when 15 minutes(15 times) arrive then particular notification are killed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really do that. Only way is to setup 15 notification in a row and keep your own list with dates. iOS is not giving you access to notification list or anything. What's more they don't have to be fired if user blocked them.

So I would advice to make own list with events + dates and manage them independently from notifications - especially when you have some important logic to be run based on that you cannot use notifications for that.

Answer (score 0):

save your counter in the user defaults in didReceiveLocalNotification:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int counter = [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"notiCounter"] intValue];
counter =+ 1;
if (counter == 15) {

} else {
    [userDefaults setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter] forKey:@"notiCounter"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

of course you have to initialize the counter and store in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: i can try all this.your suggestion is rights but it's not work in background.